# The box rearrangement algorithm in stack exchange site list page

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html, stackexchange

I am curious about one interesting and creative feature in [this stackexchange page](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid), which lists out all the stackexchange sites in grid style.

When I click on one site box, it will grow bigger and its surrounding boxes will be rearranged to fit in the whole picture.

How does the rearrangement algorithm work? Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: This is actually a 2d-variation on [bin-packing-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) (If you had to fit only lengths horizontal, without the vertical dimension, you would have got bin-packing on the lengths). Bin-Packing is NP-Hard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well judging by the source code they are using [jQuery isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin, its source code is [here](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/blob/master/jquery.isotope.js#L874). You might also want to take a look at [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Here you can find some explanation on how it can be done: http://benholland.me/javascript/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest/

Comment: Thanks! There is a lot in your answer!